# Hashing high entropy key into AES format

Tags: sha-256, sha-3, scrypt, argon2

If I have a high entropy key (ECDHE shared secret), what type of hash should I use to format this into an AES-256 key? Is Sha256 or Sha3_256 sufficient to maintain entropy or do I need to use a KDF (Scrypt / Argon2) and exchange the salt during the handshake??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to recall that shared secret keys should be hashed before using as encryption keys (some brief discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640940/libsodium-key-exchange-shared-secret-in-a-different-ways)).

If your key is already high-entropy, then hashing with SHA256 is fine. If you plan to generate several keys (ie, encryption and HMAC) from the original shared secret, then [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) is a good option. This is a key-based KDF.

Scrypt and Argon2 are password-based KDFs and are not appropriate - they're designed for low-entropy input (such as passwords).

Comment: I need to derive a key for encryption and one for a hmac, so I'll look into the HKDF. Thanks